# Check how space is distributed on a Linux system

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

I know how to check space left with:

```
df -h
```

and I know to check the space of a folder with:

```
du -ch /path/to/folder/
```

But let's say I have a 500 GB HardDisk and 350GB are used:

- Wich is the best **tool/command** to get how the space is distributed ?
- Should I do `du -ch /` ? *(I think this is not optimal)*
- There is any special **tool/app** to do this ?

I'd like an app that stores how the space is distributed in my system, wich are the space occuped in each folder...

I'd like to have something like **SpaceSniffer** *(You can check the windows tool [here](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/))*. It is a **Windows** program that examine your HardDisk and show in a easy & nice IU how the space is distributed on your computer

*This kind of software is awesome for that day you check your HardDisk and it seems you've "lost" hundred of GB's and don't know where they are !*

---

**Edit**

- I've tried **baobab** and runs/works perfectly in my **Ubuntu** machine, I tested also **JDiskReport**, here I have to fix some issues but it works in **Ubuntu** & **Windows**
- I assume **JDiskReport** will work in ***any***  OS with Java installed, **that's why I choose as correct answer**. I've tried this in Ubuntu, Windows 8, Raspbian and CentOS and works in all of them (you have to install Java)
- I have to say for those *lovers* of **command-line** your choice should be **ncdu**, it's awesome !!!

*Baobab IU:*

[image: This is the baobab IU]

Comment: Do you mean [https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/baobab/](`Disk Usage Analyzer`) (baobab)?

Comment: Exactly! I saw that after I asked the question, I'm checking it. Thanks !

Comment: In Windows you also could use *windirstat*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another very useful app for this is:

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/jdiskreport/)

Is very similar to windows ***SpaceSniffer*** and has a very useful and intuitive IU.

**You need Java to use it but it can run in every OS with Java**

The user interface:

[image: JDiskReport example in linux]

Hope it helps !

Comment: This sounds pretty nice and close to SpaceSniffer ! Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

One nice Gnome application is [baobab](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab). It comes with default ubuntu installation.

[image]

To get it,

`sudo apt-get install baobab`

```
apt-cache show baobab

Description-en: GNOME disk usage analyzer
 Disk Usage Analyzer is a graphical, menu-driven application to analyse
 disk usage in a GNOME environment. It can easily scan either the whole
 filesystem tree, or a specific user-requested directory branch (local or
 remote).
 .
 It also auto-detects in real-time any changes made to your home
 directory as far as any mounted/unmounted device. Disk Usage Analyzer
 also provides a full graphical treemap window for each selected folder.
```

Comment: This was installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 and I didn't know about it

Comment: Yes. It is a standard ubuntu program, installed to a fresh system.

Comment: If they change the name to something more noticeable or integrate it to system (setting) utility more people would find it.

Answer (score 25):

### ncdu

If you use the command line, you could use [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu). It uses a command-line GUI (ncurses).

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

**Description**

From its webpage:

> [...] ncdu: A disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface, aimed to be run
>   on a remote server where you don't have an entire gaphical setup, but
>   have to do with a simple SSH connection. ncdu aims to be fast, simple
>   and easy to use, and should be able to run in any minimal POSIX-like
>   environment with ncurses installed.

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot from the ncdu webpage]

**Example**

Check out the disk usage of your home directory:

```
ncdu ~
```

You can enter subdirectories and delete files / whole folders from within the tool.

Comment: This is awesome ! I've been trying this last minutes and its perfect

Comment: I'm used to Baobab which works great but having a command-line tool is really a nice option :) thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use the ducks:

```
du -cks *|sort -rn|head -n11
```

This will list the top ten subdirectories and files in the current path and the space they are using, and a total.

If you change the `-cks` to `-cms` it reports in MB's instead of KB's, which is probably more useful these days.

You can add x to the options on du to prevent it going into other file systems, if needbe.

(Credit: Linux Server Hacks, O'Reilly)

Comment: I use dush, for human readable sizes: 

du -sh | sort -h

Comment: @YuriC That's excellent. I'd forgotten the -h option to sort.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to collect a bounty, but the elephant in the room is missing!

`gparted` *is the application of choice for me to show how disk space is distributed* in the **entire system**.

Even for a Windows system ***prior to upgrading to Ubuntu***, as seen below:

[image: Screenshot of user prior to moving to Ubuntu]

Answer (score 2):

There is also **kde** application available on repository: [**Filelight**](https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/)

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install filelight`

```
NAME

       filelight - Graphical disk-usage information

SYNOPSIS

       filelight [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [path]

DESCRIPTION

       Allows you to exactly understand exactly your disk usage by graphically
       representating your filesystem as a set of concentric  segmented-rings.
```

Screenshot:-
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the installed tools, you could use `du -sh /*` which shows you the accumulated usage for each folder (and file) in /
You can then do this for subfolders until you found what you are looking for.
Of course, the tools mentioned in other answers are much nicer, but sometimes you can't easily install them.

Comment: I asked the question because `du` seems to be not optimal when using over path `/`. It takes too long and it's not as intuitive as the other tools. Thanks Anyways !!

Comment: if you do du -s /* it shouldn't take longer than any of the other tools!

Comment: I'll check it then !!

Answer (score 0):

Another option with simple and easy to understand interface:

1. **xdiskusage** ( sudo apt-get install xdiskusage)

   After installing call it from terminal - xdiskusage
2. **KDirStat** ( sudo apt-get install kdirstat)

This app is intended mainly for KDE.

3. **Gd map** ( sudo apt-get install gdmap)
   The Gnome alternative to  KdirsStat.

Also this link gives some more apps: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/