# Low disk space in home directory Ubuntu Mate

Tags: partitioning, mount, mate

After a fresh install of Ubuntu mate my home directory only has 230MB but I have 50GB available. How can I fix this problem ?

"Total file system capacity: 65GB (used 16G.1B: available 49.3GB)" - Disk Usage Analyzer.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           392M  1.4M  391M   1% /run
/dev/sda4        55G  9.2G   46G  17% /host
/dev/loop0      6.5G  6.0G  163M  98% /
tmpfs           2.0G   44M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/software-boutique/54
/dev/loop2      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/software-boutique/39
/dev/loop3       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop4       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop5       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop6       16M   16M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/420
/dev/loop9      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop10      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/430
/dev/loop7      7.8M  7.8M     0 100% /snap/gedit/371
/dev/loop8       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
tmpfs           392M   64K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop11     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/ncdu/6
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed something? From the mounting info above it feels like you use Ubuntu from live CD/DVD

Comment: Did you remove the LiveUSB when you rebooted?

Comment: Yes, I don't have anything plugged in. I installed Ubuntu 3 days ago but didn't had the time to test it. It's dual boot if it helps. I created a 60GB+ partition just for Ubuntu and installed it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check how space is distributed on a Linux system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561605/check-how-space-is-distributed-on-a-linux-system)